# Fishpig Wordpress Magento Post issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, fishpig

How to retrieve recent posts on the basis of its corresponding category in fishpig wordpress magento integration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$numPostsToShow = 2;
$categoryId = 1; //Replace with your category id
$recentPostCollection = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->getCollection()
    ->addIsPublishedFilter()
    ->addCategoryIdFilter($categoryId)
    ->setOrder('post_date', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize($numPostsToShow)
;
```

**EDIT**

The Fishpig Wordpress module registers the current wordpress category as 'wordpress_category'

So to answer the question in the comments as to how to get the current wordpress category dynamically:

```
Mage::registry('wordpress_category');
```

The full example above would then become:

```
$numPostsToShow = 2;
$categoryId = Mage::registry('wordpress_category')->getId();
$recentPostCollection = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->getCollection()
    ->addIsPublishedFilter()
    ->addCategoryIdFilter($categoryId)
    ->setOrder('post_date', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize($numPostsToShow)
;
```

But you should probably be using the Fishpig_Wordpress_Block_Category_View block which will give you access to `$this->_getPostCollection()` from within your template that essentially does everything above - why would you be coding this yourself when using the fishpig module?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that I want to retrieve the current category dynamically.

Comment: What current category?  Magento categories and wordpress categories are not related - Can you provide more information on the context here i.e. exactly what are you trying to achieve, where are you putting this code etc

Comment: I am telling about blog category. I have created categories in blog and added posts to the various blog categories. In Magento I am displaying posts category wise and they are displaying fine as well. Now the problem is I have to retrieve the most recent posts as per blog category. It is simply displaying recent posts from any category. I want to know how would I retrieve blog category dynamically so to retrieve its recent posts.

Comment: Thankyou very very much. You just made my day. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Drew Hunter : If we want to get categoryId in post_view then what to do ? I tried ur trick it didn't worked in post_view page : Mage::registry('wordpress_category')->getId(); as well Mage::registry('wordpress_category');