# How to display associated WordPress category's posts on Magento product page (Fishpig integration)?

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I'm having trouble filtering out just the associated category posts associated with a product in the posts.phtml block (using Fishpig).  I tried to use the following solution to get the posts:

[Fishpig Wordpress Magento Post issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774330/fishpig-wordpress-magento-post-issue)

like so:

```
$categoryId = Mage::registry('wordpress_category')->getId();
$recentPostCollection = Mage::getModel('wordpress/post')->getCollection()
    ->addIsPublishedFilter()
    ->addCategoryIdFilter($categoryId)
    ->setOrder('post_date', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize($numPostsToShow)
;
```

Then modifying the original Related Posts block:

```
<?php //$posts = $this->getPosts() ?>
<?php $posts = $recentPostCollection; ?>
<?php if (count($posts) > 0): ?>
    <div class="block block-blog block-recent-posts">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getTitle()): ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($title) ?></span></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <ul id="<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>">
                <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <?php $image = $post->getFeaturedImage(); ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape( $image->getAvailableImage() ) ?>" ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
           </ul>
           <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('<?php echo $this->getListId() ?>')</script>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And, well, that's not working.  When I put a static number into $categoryID, I can at least get data into the $recentPostCollection, but the loops does not work with that data structure...  Any help would be amazing!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
magento fishpig related posts display by category:->
<?php $categories = $post->getTermCollection('category') ?>
    <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
        <?php $getCategory = $this->escapeHtml($category->getId()); ?>
        <div id="inhouse-tab"><?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('wordpress/sidebar_widget_posts')->setTemplate('wordpress/sidebar/widget/categoryposts.phtml')->setCategoryId($getCategory)->setPostCount(4)->toHtml(); ?></div>
        <?php break; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```